# Automatically generate report from DataGrip?

Tags: automation, process, report, analysis, datagrip

I have to pull-out the same report every week from DataGrip.

Is it possible to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment - no, but here is [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-8934), please follow and vote.